# Battery on a Suzuki Marauder

Tags: battery, suzuki

I have just purchased a suzuki marauder but the battery sounds as though its flat.
can anyone tell me please where to locate this as I do not have  manual.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact year and model, I will just answer that in the vast majority of bikes the battery is under the seat. There may be a tool kit or cover under the seat that will need to be removed to access the battery.

Do an Internet search for "Suzuki Marauder manual". There are some sites where you can download a PDF of the manual.

Answer (score 1):

It should be directly under the seat. Here is an image of a Marauder with the seat removed:

[image]